# Confused why Time.deltaTime causes uneven movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move an object so that it moves visually at the same speed regardless of frame rate fluctuations.  From my understanding, I should be using `Time.deltaTime` to determine how far to move during each iteration of `Update`.  My `Update` code is like this:

```
void Update()
{
    this.rigidBody.MovePosition(this.transform.position + new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * 2f, 0, 0));
}
```

However, the object moves in faster and slower spurts as it moves across the screen.  If I move it a constant amount during each `Update` (like below), it appears to move evenly.

```
void Update()
{
    this.rigidBody.MovePosition(this.transform.position + new Vector3(0.02f, 0, 0));
}
```

I'm confused because I thought that moving an object a constant distance during each `Update` should be the thing that causes jitter since its speed would be affected by the frame rate.  And I thought that using `Time.deltaTime` should cause a constant rate of framerate-independent movement.

My `Time.deltaTime` values vary between 0.002 to 0.17, which I also don't understand because I have a very simple scene of only 2D sprites so I don't understand why the variance is so great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate the exact new position of your `RigidBody`, you should just *set* the `position` directly. E.g.:

```
this.rigidBody.position += new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * 2f, 0, 0);
```

Alternatively, execute the code you already have, but in the `FixedUpdate()` method.

The `MovePosition()` is intended to be used in the context of the `FixedUpdate()` method. Unity3d will attempt to calculate a movement rate according to the frame rate that will interpolate positions between the current position and the new position. You're confusing it by also doing that interpolation and using the result when you call `MovePosition()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize that MovePosition does its own interpolation.  I thought it just moved the object to a position instantly.